# Too many people want to DM

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

So my friends and I started a D&D group about a month ago. I am the only experienced player. Because I was the only one with any knowledge of the game, I decided to give a tutorial session as DM.

There are a total of 6 people in the group, and after this first session, 3 of the members want to be DM. They can’t decide who should be DM, and are always arguing about it. They proposed a rotating system of campaigns, but they only want the campaigns to last a couple of sessions before switching DMs. This causes the other players to not have any time to invest in their characters, because we will only be using the same characters for two or three meetings.

I think the best solution is to choose a permanent DM, and tell the other 2 to get over it. However, I don’t really want to hurt my friends' feelings. Does anyone have any solutions to this problem? I really can’t stand any more arguing.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a longer campaign work with a rotating DM, or how to run a very short (a couple sessions) campaign?

Comment: @MarkWells I think it’s pretty clear that SpaceWizzard is asking “what should we do?” which is kind of broad and a bit opinion-based, but I don’t think qualifies as *too* broad or *primarily* opinion-based. Someone experienced with such a situation can share their experience and expertise, which will provide a sound basis for people to vote up or down on the suggestion. Should work fine.

Comment: Please clarify the D&D edition and I think this can be reopened.

Answer (score 6):

### Shared World + Adventurers' Guild: a way to solve this problem

In a shared world, all who DM agree on how the world works; you then each take a sector of the world and run your campaign in it, now and again meeting as DM's to see if something that the party did changed the world substantially.

Each PC is a member of an Adventurers' Guild, which provides a hub for starting points in each given area.  Use whatever version of "a permanent teleportation circle" feature the edition has to make the movement from area to area logical in-world.  The party arrives at a Guild location in the DM's area before the sessions that DM is going to run begin.

My current group uses a shared world, three DMs.  Whoever is DMing has a player who is either "ghosting along" in the background, or has downtime duties/activities while he/she DMs and the others are taking on the adventure they are running.  You can either keep their XP about on par with the groups who is engaged, or let there be slight differences; discuss that with your whole group before you start doing this.

We have done stuff like this in three editions of the game: the original, AD&D 1e, and D&D 5e. Three of our players don't want to DM, and that's fine!  Those who do have a reliable cast of characters who move from area to area.

#### You lead by example: DM the first few sessions

Part of what you are doing is introducing new players to the game.  To pick the DM for the next few sessions after that, draw straws or ***roll dice*** to see who does the next few sessions, trying their hand as DM.  Then rotate again.

Since most are new, have "after the session" wrap ups to discuss "we liked this, we didn't like that, we are confused about this" kinds of discussions.  Learn together.  It's fun.

While I suspect that a [Westmarches style campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120770/22566) could be done this way in the current edition, I have not done that first hand in 5e (though we are a bit sand boxy in our shared world) so I won't do more than suggest that you [explore that option as well for a shared world](https://youtu.be/oGAC-gBoX9k).

Matt Colville suggests that using two other RPGs - *Microscope* and *Kingdom* - to build the world together is a way to get the players to all invest in the world.